# Words in Eclipse editor is gone

Tags: java, eclipse, ide, editor

So i don't know how this happened but this is what it's looks like right now. That long vertical line is blinking, so i think it's supposed to be the caret?
Only one line shown up :(
[image]

Until now, i haven't installed any plugins and stuff for Eclipse. Maybe it's something to do with shortcuts? Help me please?

p.s. All the text is still there, tested it by copy and paste it to notepad. Run perfectly with no errors and this only occur in this single workspace.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you open the `Windows` menu and select `Reset Perspective`, barring any view settings you really don't want to have to reconfigure.

Comment: Try hitting `CTRL`-`SHIFT`-`INSERT`, maybe you're accidentally in Insert mode.

Comment: Damn, still doesn't do anything.. this is the first time i encounter this kind of problem..

Comment: Restoring the default colors doesn't help either?

Comment: I think not.. I think all of this text is hidden in some sort of way.

Comment: Ah, i just noticed if i double click on the text editor i got this error 
    `An error has occurred. See error log for more details.
-3` and -2...

Comment: Nope, not at all.. i tried to surf the net but found nothing..

oh wait wait.. it said unhandled loop exception in the org.eclipse.ui so that mean my eclipse is broken? :\

Comment: It could maybe be this bug then, I'm not sure. My apologies for not being of greater assistance https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=402983

Comment: Nah, you've been helping that's what i need even it didn't fix it, lol need someone to talk about this to.. so, what should i do in order to avoid this?

Comment: Maybe a clean install of Eclipse?

Comment: That's a good idea but am i must create every workspace all over again? never done it before too :p sorry for being a newb

Comment: Nope, just don't delete your workspace directory and you'll be fine!

Comment: alright gonna test it now, and gonna let you know the result

Comment: Ahh, it's bad luck, nothing changes :( upgraded to eclipse luna

Edit: FIXED IT :DD i tried to backup the .metadata folder on the workspace and then run eclipse, finally importing all the projects again and bam fixed :D

Comment: That's really really strange. Well best of luck in your troubleshooting!

Comment: Thanks for your support :D btw still didn't know what's with that .metadata folder though xD